# globalVariables and Function Behavior

Tags: r, foreach, package, global-variables

Running `R CMD check` on a package of mine throws a note regarding *undefined global functions or variables*. Consider the following example:

```
mypackage: no visible binding for global variable 'a'
mypackage: no visible global function definition for '.'
mypackage: no visible binding for global variable 'b'
Undefined global functions or variables:
   . a b
```

`a` and `b` are iterators in `foreach` loops:

```
x <- foreach::foreach(a = A) %dopar% {some code}
y <- foreach::foreach(b = B) %do% {some code}
```

The dot is used in `stats::update`:

```
formula <- stats::update(formula, ~ . - 1)
```

This all works perfectly fine, and it is `R CMD check` that requires fixing, not the package. However, the repository maintainer refuses to accept the package unless I overcome this note. He recommended checking `utils::globalVariables` and I read the function's documentation and various discussions of it. What is not clear to me is whether `utils::globalVariables(c("a", ".", "b"))` would somehow interfere with the rest of my package? Would it affect the behavior or outcomes of the `foreach` loops or `stats::update`?

Comment: Yeah, everyone uses `utils::globalVariables()` to bypass the checks. I don't think it affects your output in any way.